# I created an HTML sandwich page with scroll but, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I created an HTML sandwich with a scrolling bar.

**Header**

body(scrolling table)

Footer

Nor the header neither the footer can move (and they don't), and the table in the center should scroll all its content but,
unfortunately the scrolling bar doesn't appear. I've seen lots of examples, it should work however, I don't know much about HTML.

The weird thing is that, it works here:[Snippet in LiveWeave](http://liveweave.com/yZht3F)

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){
    
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  
    $( "#btfirst" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-first"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btfirst").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});

    $( "#btprev" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-prev"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btprev").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btnext" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-next"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btnext").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btlast" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-end"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btlast").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});
});
```

```css
@font-face
{
 font-family: 'agroverdanab';
 src: url('./fonts/agroverdanab.eot');
 src: local('agroverdanab'), url('./fonts/agroverdanab.ttf') format('truetype');


 font-family: 'agroverdana';
 src: url('./fonts/agroverdana.eot');
 src: local('agroverdana'), url('./fonts/agroverdana.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html,body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#div_main{height:100%;display:flex;flex-direction:column;}

#header{border:solid 1px #79B7E7;border-bottom:0; height:3%;font-family:"agroverdanab";font-size:13px;font-weight:600}
#content{border:solid 1px #79B7E7;flex:1;}

#navdata{}
#navbar{border-bottom:solid 1px #79B7E7;padding:2px}
#navbutton{float:right;}
#msgbar{border:solid 1px #79B7E7;border-top:0; height:3%;}
#footer{border:solid 1px #79B7E7;border-top:0;height:5%; background-color: white;}
  

body{height:100%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}

table{
 table-layout:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:60%
}
table thead tr{background-color:#9BC2E6;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px}
table tbody tr.color{background-color:#DDEBF7;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px}
table tbody tr{background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:"agroverdana";font-size:12px;border:0}


#navdata {
    height:83%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#table_body{
    height:83%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#table_model{
  height: 10px;
    
}

.colgroup1 {
  height: 1px;
  background-color:#9BC2E6;
  font-family:"agroverdana";
  font-size:12px;
  text-align: center;
}
#black_corner{
  width: 12px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Central de Controle da Engenharia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div_main">
 <header id="header" style="text-align:center;">Central de Controle da Engenharia</header>

 <section id="content">
  <header id="navbar">
   
   <input type="text" id="vpad-pesq">
   <select>
    <option>Código</option>
    <option>Nome</option>
   </select>
   
   <div id="navbutton">
    <button id="btfirst"></button>
    <button id="btprev"></button>
    <button id="btnext"></button>
    <button id="btlast"></button>
   </div>   
  </header>
         
        <table id="table_model">
          <colgroup>
            <td class="colgroup1">Código</td>
            <td class="colgroup1">Descrição</td>
            <td id="black_corner"></td>
          </colgroup>
        </table>  
      
  <div id="navdata" role="main">
   <table style="overflow:auto">
    <tbody id="tbody_test">
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>002</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr class="color"><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     <tr><td>001</td><td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td></tr>
     
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </section>
 
 <section id="msgbar"></section>
 <footer id="footer">Rodapé</footer>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The scrollbar appears for me

Comment: Yeah, here: http://liveweave.com/yZht3F it appears, but when I save it as a  file and open it, it doesn't

Comment: Ahh, if you want to force a scrollbar then you'll need to set  a height on the table... `<table style="overflow:auto; max-height: 800px;">` if the page exceeds the height of the table then no scrollbar will be displayed.

Comment: oh ok, I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the scroll bar by adding an `overflow` to `#div_main`'s css styles.
Try this, it is saying when the page `overflows` on the `y-axis` to allow scrolls.

**Solution to make whole page scrollable**

```
#div_main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Solution to make just a table scrollable**

Alright, so I figured it out.. sort of. Google Chrome has a bad problem with adding scrollbars to `tbody` elements when the `tbody`'s elements are being loaded in dynamically. The only way I found through trial and error, extensive google searches, and even cracking open some old college books is that you have to 'trick it.'

Keep in mind, this isn't the cleanest answer, but it will work for what you need.

What you want to do is wrap your `tbody` with a `div`. This `div` will be what allows you to scroll.

```
<div class="scroll-table">
            <table style="overflow:auto">
                <tbody id="tbody_test">
                    <!-- <tr's> dynamically loaded -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Then you will need to set a `height` and some `scrolling` properties to your new `div`.

```
.scroll-table {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:380px;
}
```

Like I said, this is a pretty wide spread issue within the Google Chrome browser, but this is the solution that seems to be common practice. Sorry I can't come up with something a little more elegant, but this should work for what you're doing!

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3kfcacj/)** of the solution.

Comment: No I meant that I edited and just tagged you so you'd see, no worries! lol